# Show That The Number Of Odd Digits Is Itself Odd In A Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

"Suppose $n = d_k9^k + d_{k-1}9^{k-1}+...+ d_19 + d_0$ is odd. Another way of writing this would be $n = (d_kd_{k-1}...d_1d_0).$ Show that the number of digits $d_k,d_{k-1},...,d_0$ is itself odd."

**My Work So Far**

In an earlier segment of the question, I found that $d_k9^k + d_{k-1}9^{k-1}+...+ d_19$ is even, meaning that only $d_0$ determines oddness. Therefore, $d_0, d_2, d_4,d_6...$ are odd. But I don't know how to determine the upper limit of this statement, or prove that it will contain an odd number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$d_k9^k + d_{k-1}9^{k-1}+...+ d_19$ don't have to be even!

**Hint 1**

$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}: 2 \not | 9^n$

**Hint 2**

For every $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$ we have:

$2|2n\cdot(2m+1)$,
$2\not|(2n+1)\cdot(2m+1)$

**Hint 3**

Let $a_1, a_2, ... \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$:

$2|\sum (2a_i),\\
2|\sum_{i=1}^{2n} (2a_i+1), \\
2\not|\sum_{i=1}^{2n+1} (2a_i+1)$

Comment: I'm sorry, but $2|$ and $2\not |$ are unfamiliar notation to me, what are you using them to mean?

Comment: $n|k$ means, that $k$ is divisible by $n$ ($k\equiv 0 \mod n$), $n\not |k$ means $k$ is not divisible by $n$

Comment: Understood, and you're right that it does not need to be positive, that was an oversight. I'm honestly still quite confused, but you did give an answer, so I'll accept it.